# Are polypropylene pages safe to store DS and 3DS games?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I read, once upon a time, that plastic pages can create static that destroys the information stored on game cartridges.

I am trying to find a storage solution for my games, and the binder I found that fits has polypropylene pages. Will these be safe for game cartridge storage?

If it helps, [this is the binder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QEAXJE).

Comment: Someone needs to test this, For Science!

Comment: Plastic cartridge case + polyproylene + sliding + exposed contacts... I don't know if it's true, but that's a combination that makes the idea of micro-static discharges wiping data seem plausible.

Comment: You can get anti-static pages, if you feel that is a concern.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the pages. They'd be sewn into the binder. I'm not really looking for a DIY project, either - just trying to figure out if this binder I found that seems to be perfect would be great, or if I should move on.

Comment: @user56729 If this is sold specifically for carrying cartridges, it probably already uses anti-static pages. Not much way to confirm except by contacting the manufacturer, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have any research to back this up with 3DS games due to my only owning one game for that system that never leaves the slot in the back, However if the cartridges are anything like those from the previous DS systems then they should be fine. i carried my older games around in plastic boxes, with plenty of room for the contacts to slide around, and never had any problems. Also it seems that all the Amazon customers who reviewed the binder in question rated it with 5 stars. I would think if it was destroying games people would be complaining about the quality of the product.

I also have a small amount of experience in Electronics engineering from my vocational school. everything I know about electrostatic damage relates to IC chips. if the leads to these chips is touched without being grounded it can cause damage, however my experience is that once they are in the bread board that we use that they are safe to be touched.

So I theorize that the IC chips in the DS games are grounded to the circuit board on the inside, however I have never taken one apart before so I have no evidence. Follow my advice at your own risk. Maybe see what a few smarter people have to say first before considering my input.

Comment: A breadboard is *grounded*, usually via a shared negative/ground rail, which connects to the power supply, which connects to the ground pin in the supply's power cord, and eventually via the building's power mains to a ground stake driven into the earth somewhere. A 3DS cartridge is not connected to earth ground.

Comment: Thank you for your input. For the record, the reason I asked anyway is because most of the 5* ratings are "My grandchild loves that his games aren't messy" and "I JUST GOT THIS and... blahblahblah." So I'd assume they either aren't aware of the (possible) damage, or haven't played the games yet to see it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Even a grounded IC is not safe from static-shock.  What ruins the IC after rubbing your feet on the carpet and touching it is the ridiculously high current that flows through it due to the *(literally)* millions of volts difference in voltage between you and the board.  That will happen whether it is grounded or not.  The reason IC's in a metalic case are considered safe(-ish) from static shock is that the case is usually also grounded, so a person who touches the IC is highly likely to touch the case first and equalize their voltage through that instead.